# Replace string between "[]" with javascript using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string coming back from a webservice the contains open brackets like such "[]"
so the string would look like something like this:

```
[1] blabh balh blah
```

I would like to write a regexp that would remove the "[1]" or anything between open brackets.
Right now I've tried something like:

```
var regexp = /\[[]\\]/g;
```

but this does not work.  I'm stumbling on my own two feet here.
I simply just want to find anything that starts with "[" and ends with "]" and replace everything in the middle including the open and closed brackets.
Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe `/\[[0-9]*\]/;`  No need for the g flag because you don't want to replace globally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
var str = '[1] blabh balh blah';
str = str.replace(/\[.*?\]\s?/g, '');
```

If you have nested brackets regexp might no be the best option though.

Comment: dude you are my hero i feel so stupid right now!!! thank you for this answer. one quick question those the "[.*]" is that a wild card type of search? thank you i humbly thank you.

Comment: I just tried it in Firefox Web Console and it returns `blabh balh blah`

Comment: @Miguel: Yeah, `.*` means "any character 0 or more times"

Comment: @elclanrs: You should make the `.*` non-greedy.

Comment: @the system is right.  If there is a right bracket elsewhere in your sentence, you will end up replacing too much.  See http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: I know that this is a old answer but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Is using regexp a requirement?  If not, a simple solution might be:

```
var myString = '[1] Bob Loblaw is the man';
myString = myString.slice(myString.indexOf(']')+1);
```

Comment: Web Console returns " Bob Loblaw is the man".  You would need to get rid of the space also.